# Are name, address, and phone number important SEO signals for a SaaS business website?

Tags: seo, local-seo, name, address

Knowing that NAP (name, address, and phone) are important search engine optimizations for local businesses that are city specific, e.g. plumbers,  lawyers etc.

Is NAP still useful to a software as a service business, which doesn't have any physical address? i.e. users from anywhere can just register at the website for the product, so their physical location doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citations of name, address, and phone number are very important for ranking in Google Maps searches.   Google measures how "important" a local business is by counting the number of times its name, phone number, and address appear on the web.

If you don't have a physical storefront where you want to have customers show up, you don't need to worry about ranking in Google Maps.  NAP citations aren't going to matter much to your website.

You will need to do the type of SEO that most websites do:

- Links
- Social
- Copy writing
- Content creation
- Pages for about, contact us, terms of service, and privacy policy
- Reputation management

Comment: Awesome, When you say "Google maps" are you referring to the Google business/local/google_plus_business (they keep changing its name) - results that appear in googles organic search? Does that mean NAP / citations don't affect googles "regular" organic searches?

Comment: Yes I'm referring to Google local results that sometimes appear in organic search for location specific searches.  NAP citations may be a small factor in regular organic search, but if so its not big enough that I've ever seen it on any list of top SEO factors.

Answer (score 1):

NAP falls in the category of "trust signals".  There are some characteristics that legitimate web-only businesses have that illegitimate web-only businesses do not.

Legitimate web-only businesses tend to have fully fleshed-out "About Us" sections of their websites, which may include NAP.  Legitimate web-only businesses have employees, and commonly link back-and-forth between the website and the social media profiles of these employees.  Legitimate web-only businesses often register their domains for 5+ years, etc.

In isolation, implementing any 1 of these tactics isn't going to turn your untrusted website into a trusted one.  But when you provide **LOTS** of these trust signals, from a variety of sources, all telling similar stories, they tend to point to web business that is doing business in good faith, and in it for the long haul.